# How to draw bracket between node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have three boxes. They are located in nodes. I want to make a connection between them as follows:

[image]

```
\node[cubecontainer] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (b) at (4,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (c) at (8,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
```

How can I make the blue arrow and red bracket connection between them. My full code to generate three boxes is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
\newcommand{\cuboid}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pic [#1] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzstyle{cubecontainer}=[outer sep = 0pt, inner sep= 0pt]
\tikzstyle{connectarrow}=[-{Triangle[angle=60:0pt 2]},
                          line width= 10pt, shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm, draw=gray!60]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cubecontainer] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (b) at (4,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (c) at (8,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can draw the arrow like any other path and the brace is done with `decorations.pathreplacing` library.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
\newcommand{\cuboid}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pic [#1] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzstyle{cubecontainer}=[outer sep = 0pt, inner sep= 0pt]
\tikzstyle{connectarrow}=[-{Triangle[angle=60:0pt 2]},
                          line width= 10pt, shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm, draw=gray!60]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cubecontainer] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (b) at (4,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (c) at (8,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

\draw[line width=2mm, green, -latex, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] (a.north) --++(90:1cm)-|(c.north);
\draw[ultra thick, red, decoration={brace, raise=5pt, mirror, amplitude=3mm}, decorate] (a.south west) -- (c.south east);
\draw[line width=2mm, green, -latex, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] ([yshift=-5mm]b.south)--++(-90:1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks. Is it possible to locate an arrow bellow the bracket as my figure

Comment: @user8264: Done!

Comment: Nice once. I just want to ask about your using lib `decorations.pathreplacing`. Does it have any option to smooth the corner of connection?It is similar bent arrow

Comment: @user8264 What corner do you want to smooth? Your original figure doesn't show it.

Comment: Sorry. Your answer is enough for my original question. I just want to extend it. The bent arrow like this link (just 2D case) https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/3d-red-curved-arrow-shadow-pointing-385686403

Comment: @user8264: Try adding `rounded corners` as option in command corresponding to the upper link.